# How to make 'this' work properly on option?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to get "this" to work properly, but I believe that I've made an error somewhere that makes "this" to pick every option instead of individual option.

I've tried with ".each" function and then without it.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$('<input type="text" class="beruf-suche" placeholder="Berufsuchen"/>').insertAfter('.home-page .field_beruf label');

   var beruf_suche_option = $( '.home-page .field_beruf select option' );
   var beruf_suche_option_val = $( '.home-page .field_beruf select option' ).val();

   $('.beruf-suche').keyup(function() {

      if (this.value == beruf_suche_option_val) {
         $(beruf_suche_option).each(function() {
            $(this).show();
         });
      }
      else {
         $(beruf_suche_option).hide();
      }

   });
```

When I type something inside of an input text box, the option should appear if: text in input box == the option value.

Comment: You need to loop through all the `option` elements and compare their values individually.

Comment: `$(beruf_suche_option).each(function()` should be `beruf_suche_option.each(function()`

Comment: @LelioFaieta They're equivalent, his is just a little less efficient since it creates a new jQuery object.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't the first return `$($( '.home-page .field_beruf select option' ))`?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, it would. But if the argument to `$()` is a jQuery collection, it returns a new collection with the same elements.

Comment: @Barmar I see.Didn't know. Thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: `beruf_suche_option_val` is just the value of the first option. I'm not sure why you're comparing `this.value` to just that one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're calling `val()` on a collection of elements, hence the result will only be the value of the *first* `option`.

To fix this you need to loop through all the options and perform the comparison within that loop. You can then also make the loop more succinct by passing the boolean result of the comparison to `toggle()`. Try this:

```js
var $beruf_suche_option = $('.home-page .field_beruf select option');

$('.beruf-suche').keyup(function() {
  var beruf_suche_val = this.value.trim();
  $beruf_suche_option.each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(beruf_suche_val == this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it works. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, and you could modify it pretty easily, based upon what you want to match on, the val or the text.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="beruf-suche" placeholder="Berufsuchen"/>

<select>
<option value="" readonly selected>Select An Option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS/jQuery

```
var beruf_suche_options = $( 'select option' );


$('.beruf-suche').keyup(function() {

   var html = beruf_suche_options.filter( function (index) {
      return (this.value ==  $(".beruf-suche").val() ||  this.value === "");
    });
    $("select").html(html);
});
```